# r support vector machine e1071 training not working

Tags: r, svm, training-data

I am playing around with Support Vector Machines in the R-Language. Specifically I am using the e1071 package.

As long as I follow the manual pages or the tutorial at [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Classification/SVM) everythings works. But if I try to use my own datasets with those examples things aren't that good anymore.

It seems that the model creation fails for some reason. At least I am not getting the levels on the target column. Below you find the example for clarification.

Maybe someone can help me to figure out what I am doing wrong here. So here is all the code and data.

**Test dataset**

```
target,col1,col2
0,1,2
0,2,3
0,3,4
0,4,5
0,5,6
0,1,2
0,2,3
0,3,4
0,4,5
0,5,6
0,1,2
0,2,3
0,3,4
0,4,5
1,6,7
1,7,8
1,8,9
1,9,0
1,0,10
1,6,7
1,7,8
1,8,9
1,9,0
1,0,10
1,6,7
1,7,8
1,8,9
1,9,0
1,0,10
```

**R-Script**

```
library(e1071)

dataset <- read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')

tuned <- tune.svm(target~., data = dataset, gamma = 10^(-6:-1), cost = 10^(-1:1))

summary(tuned)

model  <- svm(target~., data = dataset, kernel="radial", gamma=0.001, cost=10)

summary(model)
```

**Output of the summary(model) statement**

```
+ summary(model)

Call:
svm(formula = target ~ ., data = dataset, kernel = "radial", gamma = 0.001, 
    cost = 10)

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  10 
      gamma:  0.001 
    epsilon:  0.1 

Number of Support Vectors:  28
>
```

**Wikibooks examaple**

If I compare this output to the output of the wikibooks example, it's missing some information. Please notice the "Levels"-Section in the output:

```
library(MASS)
library(e1071)
data(cats)
model  <- svm(Sex~., data = cats)
summary(model)
```

**Output**

```
> summary(model)

Call:
svm(formula = Sex ~ ., data = cats)

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.5 

Number of Support Vectors:  84

 ( 39 45 )

Number of Classes:  2 

Levels: 
 F M
```

Comment: `Sex` is probably a factor, but `target` is numeric.

Comment: Thx, that did the trick. If I change the values to x/y instead of 0/1 it works. Either in the dataset or on the fly in R with dataset$target <- as.factor(dataset$target)
dataset$target[dataset$target == 0] <- "x"
dataset$target[dataset$target == 1] <- "y"

Comment: `factor` has a `levels` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Putting Roland's answer in the proper "answer" format:

`target` is numeric

`sex` is a factor

Let me give a few more suggestions:

- it seems as if `target` really should be a factor.  (It has only 2 levels, 0 & 1, and I suspect you're trying to classify into either 0 or 1.)  So stick in a `dataset$target <- factor(dataset$target)` somewhere.
- right now, because `target` is a numeric, a regression model is being run instead of a classification.
- it's worthwhile to do a similar check for any of your variables before running a model (especially a model).  In the case you gave, for instance, it's not obvious what `col1` and `col2` are.  If either of them are a grouping or classification, you should also make them factors, too.

  - In R, many functions have multiple ways in which they will run, depending upon the data types fed to them.  If you feed factors into a model, it will run classification.  If you feed numerics, regression.  This is actually common in many programming languages, and is called [function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).